# how to pass xml as string and read objects data baed on parent tag

Tags: xml, string

i am passing this string to one method. that method has to read this string based on  tag and return staff data in the form of string.

```
String req="<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>"
+"<company>"
+"<staff id=\"1001\">"
+"<firstname>yong</firstname>"
+"<lastname>mook kim</lastname>"
+"<nickname>mkyong</nickname>"
+"<salary>100000</salary>"
+"</staff>" +"<staff id=\"2001\">"
+"<firstname>low</firstname>"
+"<lastname>yin fong</lastname>"
+"<nickname>fong fong</nickname>"
+"<salary>200000</salary>"
+"</staff>" +"</company>";
```

Comment: hI Joy, can you post a sample input and output your expecting, that would be really helpful

Comment: input is above string only. output will be                                                    1001 yong mook kim mkyong 10000    2001 low yin fong fong fong 200000

Answer (score 0):

Using JDOM:

```
String xml = "<message>HELLO!</message>";
org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder saxBuilder = new SAXBuilder();
try {
    org.jdom.Document doc = saxBuilder.build(new StringReader(xml));
    String message = doc.getRootElement().getText();
    System.out.println(message);
} catch (JDOMException e) {
    // handle JDOMException
} catch (IOException e) {
    // handle IOException
}
```

Using the Xerces DOMParser:

```
String xml = "<message>HELLO!</message>";
DOMParser parser = new DOMParser();
try {
    parser.parse(new InputSource(new java.io.StringReader(xml)));
    Document doc = parser.getDocument();
    String message = doc.getDocumentElement().getTextContent();
    System.out.println(message);
} catch (SAXException e) {
    // handle SAXException 
} catch (IOException e) {
    // handle IOException 
}
```

Using the JAXP interfaces:

```
String xml = "<message>HELLO!</message>";
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = null;
try {
    db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    InputSource is = new InputSource();
    is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
    try {
        Document doc = db.parse(is);
        String message = doc.getDocumentElement().getTextContent();
        System.out.println(message);
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        // handle SAXException
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // handle IOException
    }
} catch (ParserConfigurationException e1) {
    // handle ParserConfigurationException
}
```

Comment: can i get data based on parent tag. means every staff information .